# How to update Flutter PWA version?

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, versioning

When I publish new versions of my PWA created by Flutter web, the browser is not cached and doesn't show the new updates of PWA and reads the old cached.

Answer (score 4):

If your are using flutter 2.10 or later, when update version of your app in `pubspec.yaml` and build it serviceWorkerVersion will update your app automatically.

If browser cache your application you should refresh page once

Comment: The browser cached the application; I don't want to refresh the page manually.

Comment: Maybe this blog can help you: [https://medium.com/flutter-community/caching-in-flutter-for-web-42b3ae0e348f](https://medium.com/flutter-community/caching-in-flutter-for-web-42b3ae0e348f)